# extract values found in array from string

Tags: php, arrays

I am stuck. What I would like to do: In the $description string I would like to check if any of the values in the different arrays can be found.  If any of the values match, I need to know which one per array. I am thinking that I need to do a function for each $a, $b and $c, but how, I don't know

```
if($rowGetDesc = mysqli_query($db_mysqli, "SELECT descFilter FROM tbl_all_prod WHERE lid = 'C2'")){
  if (mysqli_num_rows($rowGetDesc) > 0){
    while($esk= mysqli_fetch_array($rowGetDesc)){
        $description = sanitizingData($esk['descFilter']);

        $a = array('1:100','1:250','1:10','2');
        $a = getExtractedValue($a,$description);

        $b = array('one','five','12');
        $b = getExtractedValue($b,$description);

        $c = array('6000','8000','500');
        $c = getExtractedValue($c,$description);
    }
  }
}

function getExtractedValue($a,$description){
?
}
```

I would be very very greatful if anyone could help me with this.

many thanks Linda

Comment: `in_array`, `array_search`

Comment: What result are you expecting to get?

Comment: @alma Do for example, if the decription is "it is 1:250 contrast and 6000 lm". I need the $a variable to extract 1:250 and so on. but I think array_search is what I am looking for

Comment: @viakondratiuk thanks, array_search I think will do the trick

Comment: @user626342 Is `$description` a **string** as you indicated in your question?

Comment: @esqew yes it is a string

Comment: You can't use `in_array` or `array_search` to help you with the searching of a string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to create each array just once and not in every iteration of the while loop.
Also using the same variable names in the loop is not recommended.

```
if($rowGetDesc = mysqli_query($db_mysqli, "SELECT descFilter FROM tbl_all_prod WHERE lid = 'C2'")){
  if (mysqli_num_rows($rowGetDesc) > 0){

    $a = array('1:100','1:250','1:10','2');
    $b = array('one','five','12');
    $c = array('6000','8000','500');

    while($esk= mysqli_fetch_array($rowGetDesc)){
        $description = sanitizingData($esk['descFilter']);    

        $aMatch = getExtractedValue($a,$description);

        $bMatch = getExtractedValue($b,$description);

        $cMatch = getExtractedValue($c,$description);
    }
  }
}
```

Use strpos to find if the string exists (or stripos for case insensitive searches). See http://php.net/strpos. If the string exists it will return the matching value in the array:

```
function getExtractedValue($a,$description) {
   foreach($a as $value) {
       if (strpos($description, $value) !== false) {
           return $value;
       }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: I refined the code. It is strange that I did return the value by looking it up in the array while it could just be returned with `$value`.

Answer (score 0):

there s a [php](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.in-array.php) function for that  which return a boolean.

or if you wanna check if one of the element in arrays is present in description, maybe you 'll need to iterate on them

```
foreach($array as element){
  if(preg_match("#".$element."#", $description){
   echo "found";
  }
}
```

Comment: User is searching a string, not an array

Answer (score 0):

If your question is correctly phrased and indeed you are searching a string, you should try something like this:

```
function getExtractedValue($a, $description) {
    $results = array();
    foreach($a as $array_item) {
        if (strpos($array_item, $description) !== FALSE) {
            $results[] = $array_item;
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

The function will return an array of the matched phrases from the string.

Answer (score -1):

Try This..

> if ( in_array ( $str , $array ) ) {
>       echo 'It exists'; } else {
>       echo 'Does not exist'; }

Comment: User is searching a string, not an array